# Adding integers from a file?

Tags: java, file

I am trying to read integers from a file and then add them to a total, and then dsplay the total. I have this code but it seems to get stuck on the while block and wasnt sure why? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HandlingExceptions {

int num;
int total = 0;

public HandlingExceptions () {
}

public void read () {
    FileReader fr;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("integers.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(br);
        try {
            num = br.read();
            while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                total = total + num;
            }
            System.out.println("THE TOTAL OF THE VALUES IS: " + total);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        scan.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("<<FILE NOT FOUND>>");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        HandlingExceptions method = new HandlingExceptions();
        method.read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing `total = total + scan.nextInt();` inside the while loop instead?

Comment: that worked thank you very much! Why is it that what I was doing wasn't working?

Comment: Also `num = br.read();` doesn't make sense, try removing this statement.

Comment: `hasNextInt` tells you there is an available `int` to read, you need to read and consume that int to make the scanner move on to the next int. You do this with `scan.nextInt()`

Comment: It did not work because `scan.hasNextInt()` tells you there is an available int but does not read it. And you never read this int.

Comment: when i removed  that it gave me an error Arnaud

Comment: thank you for expaining!

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the format of your `integers.txt` file but if the numbers are separate by a whitespace:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of("integers.txt"))) {
    int total = reader.lines()
            .flatMap(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split("\\s+")))
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .sum();
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

Do note that adding positive integers together faster or later will result in an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).